# How to make a dynamic website depending on subdomain?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

---

I'm going to try to explain my problem as clear as possible, feel free to ask me more precision if you didn't understand what I meant and forgive my mistakes, English is not my mother tongue.

---

### My goal

I have a website, [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), that I want to use for multiple clients (brands). 
For each brand I want to dynamically load different images / brand name / color schemes, etc. 
Each website will be on a different subdomain, like [www.brand1.mywebsite.com](http://www.brand1.mywebsite.com), [www.brand2.mywebsite.com](http://www.brand2.mywebsite.com) etc. 
I want to store my code only in one place, and all the vhost for each subdomain to use the same base of the code, but loading dynamically all I want depending on the current subdomain the user is on.

---

### The things you have to know

1. This is my first JavaScript project, I'm a PHP developer
2. I'm using NextJS (ReactJS framework) with material-ui ([this is what I used as a base](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)), because of material-ui the website use Server Side Rendering (SSR from now on)
3. For now I'm working with a json config file for each brand (that I'm trying to load dynamically) but in the future I'd like to find a way to store these informations in the database

---

### What I've tried so far

To reach that goal, I tried a bunch of things. I'm not going to talk about all of them because none of them worked so far. \

The current state of things is :

- A config file for each brand, exporting the variables I'll use later in the code

  ```
  export const ConfigBrand1 = {
      theme: {
          palette: {
              primary:{
                  light: '#314ce3',
                  main: '#fd0000'
              }
          } 
      }
  }
  ```
- A "loader.js" file that I would like to include in all the files that will need to use variables from the config file like this :
  `import { Config } from './config/loader.js';`
  and then I'm using the variable like this :
  `Config.theme.palette.primary.light`
- The load.js file look like this :

  ```
  import { brand1 } from './brand1.js';
  import { brand2 } from './brand2.js';

  function getConf(){
      return brand1;
  }

  export const Config = getConf();
  ```

And this is working properly for 1 brand. My problem is that I can't find a way to switch between the brands according to the subdomain I'm on.

`window.location` is not working because window is not defined as we're using SSR, so I can't get the current subdomain like that.

I tried to use it in the _app.js file as well with no success.
I also tried to use ReactJS router but can't find a working syntax to use it, I don't think I can.

My questions are simple :

- Do I have the right way of thinking ? (trying to use subdomains to dynamically load config files)
- Is there a way get the subdomain from a SSR file ?
- If not, how should I proceed to do what I want to do ?

If you need any more precision, feel free to ask !

Comment: if its SSR, your need look into grabbing `req.headers.host` and doing in [`MyDocument.getInitialProps`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js#L29).. from `ctx.req`

Answer (score 1):

As Lawrence said in the comment above - you need to get the request headers - Add that via a getServerSideProps in the page you use.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) 
 const hostDomain = context.req.headers.host;
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't find a way to make this work for now but this seems to be a good solution. I'll keep trying to make this work for now.